# issues with show array in one row in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

[image]

I want to show one agent per row with all appointments, call backs, etc...

I tried to put in for loop within for loop. But, It's not giving me correct result.

CODE:

```
foreach($agents_summary as $as){
<tr>
  <td><?=$as['index']?></td>
  ... etc...
</tr>
```

ARRAY SAMPLE:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [agent_id] => 1
        [first_name] => Ronak
        [last_name] => Patel
        [transaction_type] => APPOINTMENT
        [transaction_count] => 5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [agent_id] => 1
        [first_name] => Ronak
        [last_name] => Patel
        [transaction_type] => CALL_BACK
        [transaction_count] => 5
    )
 .....
 AND SO ON...
```

EDIT:
DATABASE QUERY:

```
SELECT
a.id AS agent_id,
a.first_name AS first_name,
a.last_name AS last_name,
ct.transaction_type AS transaction_type,
count(*) AS transaction_count
FROM agent AS a
INNER JOIN client_transaction AS ct
ON a.id=ct.generated_by_id
WHERE ct.transaction_type = 'APPOINTMENT'
OR ct.transaction_type = 'CALL_BACK'
OR ct.transaction_type = 'SENT_EMAIL'
OR ct.transaction_type = 'SALE'
GROUP BY agent_id, transaction_type
ORDER BY `agent_id` ASC, `transaction_type` ASC
```

Comment: How are you retrieving this data?

Comment: The array is coming from database..

Comment: You may want to first think about how you are retrieving your data...

Comment: In your DB query, try adding `LIMIT 1` if you only want one. @user3067928

Comment: I can not do limit 1.. see my edit

Comment: Did you try taking the `<tr></tr>` tags out of the foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY agent_id` at the end of your SQL request

EDIT:
There would be a PHP solution with a for loop that would just merge the different values based on the unique agent_id:

```
$agents = array();
foreach($agents_summary as $as){
    $agents[$as['agent_id']]['first_name'] = $as['first_name'];
    $agents[$as['agent_id']]['last_name'] = $as['last_name'];
    if(empty($agents[$as['agent_id']][$as['transaction_type']])){
        $agents[$as['agent_id']][$as['transaction_type']] = $as['transaction_count'];
    }
    else{
        $agents[$as['agent_id']][$as['transaction_type']] += $as['transaction_count'];
    }
}

foreach($agents as $agentID => $agent){
    <tr>
      <td><?=$agentID?></td>
      <td><?=$agent['first_name']?></td>
      <td><?=$agent['APPOINTMENT']?></td>
      ... etc...
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: I need transaction type as in group by to separate all transactions.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. but we can not separate transaction type by means of php here. I am getting this array for variable $as in php: `Array ( [agent_id] => 1 [first_name] => Ronak [last_name] => Patel [transaction_type] => APPOINTMENT [transaction_count] => 15 ) Array ( [agent_id] => 3 [first_name] => Agent [last_name] => A [transaction_type] => SALE [transaction_count] => 4 )`

Comment: We are not even getting all transactions type here, just because we removed transaction type from GROUP BY